# How to score elastic query results on dynamic derived attributes of documents

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, full-text-search, information-retrieval

I have a question on information retrieval patterns.

I have close to 10 Mil Documents in my search cluster like these

```
    {
   "id":"7ftCdTQAAAAJ",
   "authors":[
      {
         "name":"Makoto Satoh",
         "org":"Shinshu University",
         "id":2312688602
      }
   ],
   "title":"Preliminary Design of a Network Protocol Learning Tool Based on the Comprehension of High School Students: Design by an Empirical Study Using a Simple Mind Map",
   "abstract":"Preliminary Design of a Network Protocol Learning Tool Based on the Comprehension of High School Students: Design by an Empirical Study Using a Simple Mind Map Preliminary Design of a Network Protocol Learning Tool Based on the Comprehension of High School Students: Design by an Empirical Study Using a Simple Mind Map",
   "year":2013,
   "n_citation":1,
   "doc_type":"Conference",
   "publisher":"Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg",
   "volume":"",
   "issue":"",
   "references":[
      2005687710,
      2018037215
   ]
}
```

I want to design a system that returns top k authors by h-index given a query could be something like *Top books for Network Protocol Learning Tool *
FYI H-Index is a score to calculate effectiveness of authors more info available [here](https://beckerguides.wustl.edu/authors/hindex#:%7E:text=The%20h%20index%20is%20a%20metric%20for%20evaluating%20the%20cumulative,have%20not%20yet%20been%20cited.)

How to calculate H-Index from number of citations is explained [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/h-index/description/)

One approach is to fetch all matching documents on search query group by author, fetch all citations of all authors and sort by citation count, compute h-index, then rank all results basis of h-index scores. This approach is terribly slow

we thought of two alternative approaches

1 : We tried storing h-index of all authors on documents, however indexing of new docs would be very frequent which will cause very frequent update operations due to 1:M relations of authors to articles.

2 : we can have a secondary index just to store H-Index score of authors for every batch insert and use two queries to deliver results.

My question is how can we optimise such query operations, from documentation i got to know about  Elasticsearch's "script_score" feature. However in my use case i need to fetch all articles of the author and then calculate h-index score for all matched authors including most recently indexed docs.

Can Someone suggest how you guys tackle such problems, is there any information retrieval patterns in-built in elasticsearch at form of plugins which could be utilised in such cases.

Writing a plugin might be the solution, but there is not much documentation available on writing a plugin.

Maybe another solution could be to implement the h-index calculation algorithm using painless ?

Any recommendation would be helpful, Thanks in advance

Comment: As I understand you have an author index and would like a search to be impacted by the H-Index metric.
In my opinion, you can have a field within the author's document that represents the value of this metric. You would have a service that would be responsible for calculating the h-index value and updating the document.
In the search you could use [field value factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) to impact the search with the h-index value that is already in the document.

Comment: Thanks @rabbitbr, H_index is calculated from number of citations(n_citations) in document , logic of calculation of h-index is explained [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/h-index/description/) ,I am just curious would a service updating so many documents can cause any harm to ES Cluster, or if better is there any plugin or extension in ES to automate this Score calculation for me in ES internally. Thanks again

Comment: As for the H Index, I believe it's better to have your own service to perform the calculation and updates.  How often will your documents be updated?  There are several approaches to bulk updating.  I can quote the Bulk Api and you can combine it with a queue service to pace the updates.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply, I did an estimation our frequency of updates is 200 articles/Minute with average 60 Distinct authors

Comment: Using the Bulk API you will have good results.  We used it in a situation similar to yours, we update several documents per minute and our clusters don't have any problems.